# gettext on embedded systems?

Tags: c, embedded, gettext

Does there exist a minimal gettext implementation for small embedded systems? I need to translate my application to a few different languages. The application runs on a 50MHz ARM7 cpu with FreeRTOS and a minimal libc, but does not have a file system. I have looked at the GNU gettext tools, but the task of porting libintl on my platform looks a bit daunting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Localization can be a huge pain in embedded systems.  There are a couple of things to first consider: will your translated languages require alternate character sets? Are you displaying text to a graphical display or a something like a serial console?

If the set of translated languages is relatively small and the set of text strings is well-defined, you might avoid a full-blown translation library.  I inherited an embedded product that used a set of language-specific string tables.  Each text element had a position in the table, thus a particular translated piece of text could be looked up in a 2D table by language, then by element.  (These tables were stored in ROM in this application.)

If you go this route, there are a number of other issues to consider.  Some languages  can express content more or less concisely than English. German is a good example - simple phrases can take on sentence-like lengths. As a result, you should be prepared for the case in which one text element varies substantially in length from language to language.  In my inherited app, this was done by extending the table to 3D such that a text element could have more than one "line".  Of  course, text layout (abbreviations, sentence length, pagination, etc.) extend from this, as well.

If ROM space is limited, you might consider translated snippets of phrases, then pasting them together as needed.  This so-called string consolidation approach can be tricky because the desired localized phrase might translate clumsily into snippets.  In other words, be prepared for "Engrish" if you paste snippets of translated text together willy-nilly.  Babelfish, et al, can help - but the defense is a good in-country review of the end product by a native speaker.  (Note: the native speaker should represent an "average" dialect.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're driving a LCD it might be worthwhile looking at EasyGui - www.easygui.com - because it has a translation module making it really easy to manage the translations.

You can look at the display layout on your PC and change languages on the fly, checking that the text fits into the space allocated.

There is also a translation add-on which is an EXE you can send to a translator so they can see the various languages and how it works on the screen.